# cant find symbol - method add(E)

Tags: java

I've been working on an assignment which requires me to pretty much make my own ArrayList without using any built in functions (I know theres a class for it) which brings me to a problem I am having. Where the asterisks are I'm getting a "can't find symbol - method add(E)" but I'm not sure why. 
I've also added the two add methods also I looked at various other posts about this issue and understood little about there explanation since I'm still kind of new. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
public E[] slice(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (endIndex - beginIndex > 0)
        if (beginIndex >= 0 && endIndex < size) { 
           E[] newList = (E[])(new Object[endIndex - beginIndex]);
           for (int i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
                **newList[i].add(data[i]);**
           return newList;
        }else
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return null;

public void add(E newValue)
{
    if (size == data.length) {
        E[] newData = (E[])(new Object[data.length*2]);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            newData[i] = data[i];
        data = newData; 
    }
    data[size] = newValue;
    size++;

public void add(int index, E newItem) 
{
    set(index, newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`newList[i]` is of type E, not of your array list type, so it doesn't have an add method.

It would make more sense to change

```
newList[i].add(data[i])
```

to

```
newList[i] = data[i];
```